# Reset for game and winner issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reset

I'm building a simple tic-tac-toe game and I need some help with my reset button and winner function.

At the end of provided snippet I'm trying to implement a reset button, but I'm not exactly sure how to get it to work. The way I'm doing my `else` statement for my winner function is so, that if there are no more moves, I can't seem to get it to say: "no more moves" without it saying it every time you click on a square.

**How can I implement this?**

```
// IIFE
(function() {

    angular
        .module("myApp", [])
        .controller("tictactoeController", tictactoeController);

    // Controller
    function tictactoeController() {

        // Capture Variable
        var self = this;

        self.currentTurn = '';
        self.playerOne = 'X';
        self.playerTwo = 'O';
        self.winner = '';

        // Gameboard
        self.boxes = [
            {square: 1}, {square: 2}, {square: 3},
            {square: 4}, {square: 5}, {square: 6},
            {square: 7}, {square: 8}, {square: 9} ];

        // Picks Random Player To Be X or O
        self.random = function() {
            if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                alert("Player One GO!");
                self.currentTurn = "X";
            } else {
                alert("Player Two GO!");
                self.currentTurn = "O";
            }
        };

        self.random();

        // Clickbox Function
        self.clickbox = function($index) {
            //console.log(self.boxes[$index].value + "check");
            if (self.boxes[$index].value === undefined) {
                self.boxes[$index].value = self.currentTurn;
                self.boxes[$index].square = self.currentTurn;
                if (self.currentTurn === "X") {
                    self.currentTurn = "O";
                } else {
                    self.currentTurn = "X";
                }
            } else {
                alert(
                    "Already Taken! Choose Another Square!"
                );
            }
            // Check for winner after each click
            self.winner(self.boxes[$index].value);
        };

        // Winner Fucntion
        self.winner = function(input) {

            // Row Wins
            if ((self.boxes[0].square == input && self.boxes[
                        1].square == input && self.boxes[2]
                    .square == input) || (self.boxes[3].square ==
                    input && self.boxes[4].square == input &&
                    self.boxes[5].square == input) || (self
                    .boxes[6].square == input && self.boxes[
                        7].square == input && self.boxes[8]
                    .square == input)) {
                alert(input + " WINS!");

                // Column Wins
            } else if ((self.boxes[0].square == input &&
                    self.boxes[3].square == input && self.boxes[
                        6].square == input) || (self.boxes[
                        1].square == input && self.boxes[4]
                    .square == input && self.boxes[7].square ==
                    input) || (self.boxes[2].square ==
                    input && self.boxes[5].square == input &&
                    self.boxes[8].square == input)) {
                alert(input + " WINS!");

                // Diagonal Wins
            } else if ((self.boxes[0].square == input &&
                    self.boxes[4].square == input && self.boxes[
                        8].square == input) || (self.boxes[
                        2].square == input && self.boxes[4]
                    .square == input && self.boxes[6].square ==
                    input)) {
                alert(input + " WINS!");


                // No Winner
            }
        };

        // Reset Game Button
        self.resetbtn = function() {


        };
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reset function:

```
self.resetbtn = function() {
    self.boxes.forEach(function(box, index) {
        self.boxes[index].value = '';
        self.boxes[index].square = index;
    })
};
```

The no more moves else:

```
var hasMoves = false;
self.boxes.forEach(function(box, index) {
    if(box.square != self.playerOne && box.square != self.playerTwo) {
        hasMoves = true;
    }
}

if(! hasMoves) {
    alert  ("No more moves!");
}
```

Also, it would be better if in the code you don't use hard coded values `X` and `O` but their variables `self.playerOne` and `self.playerTwo`. It will make it easier to change the values X and O (though in a Tic Tac Toe game you wouldn't do it).

Comment: Inputing the resetbtn function for each is only hiding the values. It isn't totally getting rid of them... Is there a way to refresh the page once a player hits the reset button?

Comment: You can do a page refresh: `location.reload();`, but it isn't the right solution. What do you mean by `it isn't totally getting rid of them` ? Where are the values stored ? What are the defaults ? What should be reset ?

Comment: @DustinBaker, can you answer my questions?

Comment: The values were still be stored within the console... I ended up figuring things out and got things to work. I'm not at my computer right now but will post my code later to show you what exactly I pulled off. Thanks for all the help!!! :o)